# CSS Flexbox (or Grid): 2 columns, row-wrapping, no growth, inner margins

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to get results like this image (mocked up):

[image: Example]

This is what I've tried so far, but it's clearly not working right.

```css
.flex-container {
 width: 50%;
 border: 2px dashed blue;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.flex-container > .wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 margin: -5px;
}
.flex-container > .wrapper > input {
 flex-basis: 45%;
 flex-shrink: 1;
 flex-grow: 1;
 margin: 5px;
}

.wrapper.alt1 > input {
 flex-basis: 50%;
 flex-grow: 0;
}

.wrapper.alt2 > input {
 flex-basis: 45%;
 flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
 <div class="wrapper alt1">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
 <div class="wrapper alt2">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
 </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting a dynamic list of buttons and I'd prefer to set the width to a specific % instead of rounding it down to something less specific just to make the flexbox work. Or if there's an alternative way to set the number of columns to a specific number that would be fine.

**Edit:** I'm editing to specify that the *amount* of buttons is dynamic, so it may be an odd amount or an even amount. This doesn't matter in regards to the left-aligned example, but for the centered-final-item example this could be problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider CSS grid for this:

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

input {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.alt :nth-child(odd):last-child {
  grid-column: 2/span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
</div>


<div class="container alt">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
</div>

<div class="container alt">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. As with the answer by 04FS, the first part is perfect but the second part doesn't align properly if there are an even number of buttons. Do you think there is a solution for that?

Comment: Also, thank you for providing a `grid` example. I wasn't familiar but a quick perusal is proving very interesting.

Comment: Ha, yes I just figured this out myself after cluing in that I could combine both pseudo selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the margins on the side, go with `flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 5px);` for the item width, and `justify-content: space-between;` on the flex parent.

To get the second version with the last element centered, you can simply set its side margins `auto`.

```css
.flex-container {
 width: 50%;
 border: 2px dashed blue;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.flex-container > .wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 margin-top: -10px;
}
.flex-container > .wrapper > input {
 flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 5px);
 margin-top: 10px;
}

/*
  make that
  .flex-container > .wrapper.alt1 > input:nth-child(odd):last-child
  actually, so that it only applies to last child when it's an odd one
*/
.flex-container > .wrapper.alt1 > input:last-child {
 margin: 10px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
 <div class="wrapper alt1">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
  <input type="button" value="Example">
 </div>
</div>
```

Should the negative margin-top of the wrapper affect the rest of the layout, you can also cancel the margin-top for the first two items instead,

```
.flex-container > .wrapper > input:nth-child(1),
.flex-container > .wrapper > input:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The first part is perfect. But the second part only works if there are an odd number of buttons. If there are an even amount the final button is misaligned. Do you think there is a solution for that?

Comment: @therks my bad, did not consider this edge case - which at 50:50 probability isn't that "edgy". Easy fix, let's apply the auto margin to the last child only, if it is also an odd child. Change that last selector to `.flex-container > .wrapper.alt1 > input:nth-child(odd):last-child`

Comment: Like I commented in the other answer I just figured this out myself after cluing in that I could combine both pseudo selectors. I really don't know who to award the acceptance to. 

Comment: I decided to accept Temani's answer, as I feel the grid based solution is probably the more appropriate solution to what I was doing. It seems grid is better intended for a more rigid layout like what I have and flex is intended for more, well, as the name indicates, flexible layouts. But thank you very much for your input!

Comment: Fine by me, no worries. The difference between flex and grid is a bit more about their "dimensionality" though, not really "rigid vs flexible" - flexbox works based on _one_ main axis, grid is more for two-dimensional, well - grids. You're kinda "buying" that second dimension when using flexbox, by allowing the items to wrap - that splits your one main axis into multiple ones, so to speak. Both tools can get the job done here, so pick whichever you feel more comfortable with.